# C Macro Behavior

Tags: c, macros

I have the simple following C code

```
#define Sqrt(A) A * A


int main(void) {

    int A = 10;

    int x = Sqrt(A+1);

    return 0;

}
```

For some reason, when I used it like that, with A+1, I get x to be 21, which is probably 10+11.
My question is, how is the multiplication is being ignored?
If I switch the macro with the macro text, I get the right result which is 121.

Thanks.

Comment: Always put parenthesis around your macro variables.  Remember, they are expanded prior to compilation, so any expansion which could result in odd order of operations can happen.  Parenthesis stop that.

Comment: It's this type of behavior that makes some people hate macros. If you can find an alternate method to macros (like defining a function), you should seriously consider that (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 5):

First, your `Sqrt` is misnamed, should be `Square` (not *square root*)

Then, generate the preprocessed form (i.e. with `gcc -C -E`) and look inside it.

```
 #define Sqr(A) A * A

 int a = 10;

 int x = Sqr(a+1);
```

where the last line is expanded as

```
 int x = a+1 * a+1;
```

Which is parsed as

```
 int x = a+(1*a)+1;
```

Moral of the story, always use extra parenthesis in macro definition, i.e.

```
 #define Sqr(A) ((A)*(A))
```

Even with such a definition, `Sqr(a++)` is probably undefined behavior and at least is naughty.

So you want to avoid macros and actually, learn to use inline functions like

```
 inline int square(int a) { return a*a; };
```

BTW, you will want to make it `static inline` not just `inline` (and put that in a header file)

Answer (score 3):

'cos

```
#define Sqrt(A) A * A
```

makes

```
Sqrt(A+1);
```

translate to

```
A + 1 * A + 1
```

and A is 10

so you get

10 + 1 * 10 + 1

Now do the maths!

BTW sqrt has seems to say square root not squared!

Answer (score 3):

You define the macro as `A * A`. So, `Sqrt(A + 1)` expands to `A + 1 * A + 1`, which is, due to operator precedence, equal to `2 * A + 1` - you've got `2 * 10 + 1 = 21`.

That's why you should **always parenthesize your macros and their arguments:**

```
#define Sqrt(A) ((A) * (A))
```

By the way, why a macro? What if one day you write `Sqrt(A++)`? Then you can expect [nasal demons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc). It would be safer to write an inline function instead (horribile dictu, a **correctly named** inline function):

```
static inline double square(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the macro, `A` is replaced with whatever was passed into the macro invocation. In this case, that is `A+1`. This means that the macro gets expanded to:

```
A+1 * A+1
```

Due to operator precedence, this is interpreted as `A + 1*A + 1`, or `10 + 10 + 1 = 21`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the macro as `#define Sqrt(A) ((A) * (A))`

Answer (score 0):

Macros are substituted literally and then evaluated.

Since multiplication has more priority than addition, when you give `A+1` to the macro it becomes `10 + 1 * 10 + 1` => `10 + 10 + 1` => `21`

Likewise if you give `A+2` ..... `10 + 2 * 10 + 2` => `10 + 20 + 2` => `32`.

Answer (score 0):

BODMAS rule buddy!! as the previous answers suggests. Multiplication takes place before your addition.
Your opertaion Sqrt(A+1) where A = 10 will evaulate to 10+1*10+1
10+10+1
21!!

Answer (score 0):

```
when you call x = MACRO_NAME(A+1); this statement is replace as x = A + 1 * A + 1
in c priority of multiplication is more than addition so it will be 1st executed 1*A which give as A, then A+A+1 will give you result as 21`enter code here`
i.e  A+1*A+1 
  =  A+A+1 
  =  21
for proper answer you need to write Macro as #define MACRO_NAME(A) (A) * (A) which give you result as 
121
```